# Newly inserted HTML not acting with JS event handling with Rails Nested Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, jquery-events

I am using nested_forms with Rails 4 along with turbo-links + jQuery plugin to make it restart on page loads.  Once I add a nested field with markup that should triggers events, it fails to do some, seeming like only content on initial page load can trigger the js events.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.address_input_type').on('change', function(){
    showAppropriateAddressFields(this);
  })
});
```

So `function showAppropriateAddressFields` will fire if the '.address_input_type' is on the page initially but if added in afterwards it fails.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the elements are newly inserted, you'll need to use [event delegation](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('change', '.address_input_type', function(){
    showAppropriateAddressFields(this);
  })
});
```

Try to find a closer parent element than `document` (such as a container div) to use as the selector, as using `document` isn't very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you query the DOM at the time of page load for a class, you will return an array-like-object of nodes that will not update itself when other nodes with that class are later added. Append it to the page from the beginning and set it's style "display: none".

Comment: @null has a cleaner solution. As he suggested, it's a more expensive operation.

Comment: I also was dynamically creating fields after page load (where I did not know the outcome).  Thank you for explaining the process!